# NSNotification on device reboot

Tags: ios, iphone, nsnotificationcenter, reboot

Is there a way to know when the device is rebooted in ios, like "BOOT_COMPLETED" permission in android. Went through internet and could not find and appropriate answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lithium3141/BootLaunch

You can refer this page but one think, if your app doesn't have voip feature means Apple will reject your application.

**Apple State in their document:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1

**UIBackgroundModes**

> **voip**-The app provides Voice-over-IP services. ***Apps with this key are automatically launched after system boot*** so that the app can
>   reestablish VoIP services. Apps with this key are also allowed to play
>   background audio.
>
> **remote-notification**-The app uses remote notifications as a signal that there is new content available for download. When a remote
>   notification arrives, ***the system launches or resumes the app in the
>   background and gives it a small amount of time to download the new
>   content.***

This value is supported in **iOS 7.0 and later**.

**voip** key is the technique used most of the voip applications like **skype**.

Comment: the boot launch will give the last boot time. My need is that i want to know as soon as the device booted?. Mine is not an VOIP app so cant use it. Thanks for the answer but it is not the thing i'm looking for

Comment: so the answer is **not possible** with current sdk.

Comment: so there is no nsnotification provided by apple. Like the one with batter state??